# How to sort an EAV model that have null values?

Tags: sql

We have an EAV ([Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) data model that can be simplified with those 3 tables:

[image]

We want to sort entities on certain field:

```sql
SELECT entities.*
FROM entities
  JOIN values ON values.entity_id = entities.entity_id
  JOIN fields ON fields.field_id = values.field_id
WHERE fields.name = 'my-field'
ORDER BY values.value DESC
```

However, this will not include entities that do not have values for this field.
The wanted behavior would be to have those `NULL` entries at the beginning of the result, like usual `ORDER BY`.

Do you have suggestion of how to include those values ?
Thanks

**EDIT:** Here is a concrete example:

Imagine we want to display and sort a list of 3 users, which are 3 entities having 2 fields, `name` and `age`:

The `Entity` table:

```
entity_id 
---------
       1         
       2       
       3
```

The `Field` table:

```
field_id | name
---------|-------------
       1 | "firstname"
       2 | "age"
```

The `Value` table:

```
entity_id | field_id |     value
----------|----------|-----------
        1 |        1 |   "Alice"
        2 |        1 |     "Bob"
        3 |        1 | "Charlie"
        1 |        2 |      "24"
        2 |        2 |      "27"
```

Here, Charlie have no value for `age`. How to **sort** users by the `age` field without removing Charlie ?

The above query will remove it from the result-set.

Comment: Can you give an example with data as actual versus expected result?

Comment: @Scratte I edited the question to provide a concrete example of the problem

Comment: EAV, natural joins. I'm going to have nightmares tonight.

Comment: You need to use an `OUTER JOIN` to do what you want. I recommend that you do not use `NATURAL JOIN`. It invites bugs.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Haha yeah I updated to use normal JOIN ON, I actually never use raw SQL but DB layers and ORMs. The DB was designed on an EAV model before I arrived, that's sad x) 

Indeed an OUTER JOIN should solve the issue, I will try it

Comment: Well, `FULL OUTER JOIN` does not seem to be usable because there is the `Value` table in-between that filter out non-existent results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm still somewhat confused about what you want your resultset to look like.

```
select *
  from value v1
  left join value v2 on (v1.entity_id = v2.entity_id 
                         and v2.field_id = 2)
 where v1.field_id = 1 -- assuming all users have a name
 order by v2.value;
```

Result:

```
ENTITY_ID | FIELD_ID |     VALUE |  ENTITY_ID | FIELD_ID | VALUE
----------|----------|-----------|------------------------------
        1 |        1 |   "Alice" |          1 |        2 | "24"
        2 |        1 |     "Bob" |          2 |        2 | "27"
        3 |        1 | "Charlie" |       null |     null | null
```

---

Or if you prefer the names of the fields:

```
select v1.entity_id, f1.name, v1.value, f2.name, v2.value
  from value v1
  join field f1 on v1.field_id = f1.field_id
  left join value v2 on (v1.entity_id = v2.entity_id 
                         and v2.field_id = 2)
  left join field f2 on v2.field_id = f2.field_id                         
 where f1.name = 'firstname' -- assuming all users have a name
 order by v2.value;
```

Result:

```
ENTITY_ID | NAME        |     VALUE |  NAME | VALUE
----------|-------------|-----------|--------------
        1 | "firstname" |   "Alice" | "age" |  "24"
        2 | "firstname" |     "Bob" | "age" |  "27"
        3 | "firstname" | "Charlie" |  null |  null
```

---

For the case where there's an entity, that doesn't have a firstname, I added two rows to entity and a row to value:

```
insert into entity values (4);
insert into entity values (5);
insert into value values (4, 2, '102');
```

If a record exists in the entity table, it will always be in this result:

```
select *
  from entity e
  left join value v1 on (e.entity_id = v1.entity_id
                         and v1.field_id = 1) -- firstname
  left join value v2 on (e.entity_id = v2.entity_id 
                         and v2.field_id = 2) -- age
-- order by v2.value IS NULL; -- age nulls last
```

Result:

```
ENTITY_ID | ENTITY_ID |   FIELD_ID |     VALUE |  ENTITY_ID | FIELD_ID | VALUE
----------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|----------|------
        1 |         1 |          1 |   "Alice" |          1 |        2 |  "24"
        2 |         2 |          1 |     "Bob" |          2 |        2 |  "27"
        4 |      null |       null |      null |          4 |        2 | "102"
        3 |         3 |          1 | "Charlie" |       null |     null |  null
        5 |      null |       null |      null |       null |     null |  null
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try your suggestion and the one of @Nick.McDermaid with a normal OUTER JOIN. I keep you posted

Comment: @DidiBear I think the "normal" outer join is really a "full" outer join. This explains the differences: https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-left-right-and-full-outer-join.html

Comment: Yeah I know it, it's just a bit complex to manage since MySQL does not support it -_-'

Comment: I just ran the queries against a MySql at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e32d305368fe3884857a3458ea3e3823. left join works fine. I can't speak for what Nick meant, but a left join IS an outer join :)

Comment: Thanks for the sharing :) Your suggestion that use a side value to populated entities is fine in this particular case. However, it does not work in if we only have the `age` field. Is there a solution in such case ? (Note that I can use multiple queries)
=> The only goal is to order entities, nothing else

Comment: @DidiBear I added a query to find all entities no matter what values they have. If my answer resolves your question, kindly accept it :)

Comment: Thanks, this give me a way to solve the issue ! I added a answer to what I finally use

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Scratte answer, here is one solution for my problem:

The idea is to avoid doing the `WHERE` condition on the `Field` because it filters out entities with no value. So, the solution is to retrieve the field id beforehand then do the `LEFT JOIN` using this `id`:

```sql
field_id = SELECT field_id FROM fields WHERE name = "my-field"

SELECT entities.* FROM entities 
LEFT JOIN values ON values.entity_id = entities.entity_id
                 AND values.field_id = field_id
--               ^^^ this second condition have to be here and not in the WHERE clause
ORDER BY values.value DESC
```